# Why does passing a struct in this way produce a segfault?

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to get the hang of c and I can't figure out why this code is producing a segfault.

```
// In src/test.c

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int length;
    int *arr[1000];
} Stack;

void push(Stack *stack, int el) {
    (*stack->arr)[stack->length++] = el;
}

int pop(Stack *stack) {
    return (*stack->arr)[--stack->length];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Stack stack;
    push(&stack, 5);
    printf("%d\n", pop(&stack));
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile and run:

```
$ gcc src/test.c -o test && ./test
[1]    79484 segmentation fault  ./test
```

Comment: Well, which line is causing the error???

Comment: I'm not even sure how to find out, but after narrowing down the code to this I'm fairly certain it's in the `push` or `pop` function. Still *very* new to c.

Comment: You're not initializing `stack.length`. (And compile with `-g` and use `gdb` to debug.)

Comment: Is `int *arr[1000]` really what you wanted?

Comment: Also, you are confusing an array of pointers with a pointer to array, and you don't allocate memory for your pointers.

Comment: @Mat initializing `stack.length` fixed it for me (though now in my actual program I'm getting a bus error, I'll have to investigate that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few problems.

Like others have mentioned, your `int length struct member` is never set to zero and thus could contain anything.

You must set the length to 0.

Second, `int *arr[1000]` is an array of `integer pointers`. So simply assigning an `int` to a particular array position is wrong.

You want something more like this:

```
// In src/test.c

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int length;
    int arr[1000]; // Code change (create an array of integers)
} Stack;

void push(Stack *stack, int el) {
    stack->arr[stack->length++] = el; // Code change (no need for additional
                                      // structure member dereference).
}

int pop(Stack *stack) {
    return stack->arr[--stack->length]; // Code change (no need for additional
                                        // structure member dereference).
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Stack stack;
    stack.length = 0; // Code change (set the starting length value to 0)
    push(&stack, 5);
    printf("%d\n", pop(&stack));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your structure, "length" is never initialized, so it contains garbage.  WHen you then reference:

```
(*stack->arr)[stack->length++]
```

it is indexing memory at an undefined location.  So, you need some function, like "init_stack()" to initialize the structs data members to well known values (like zero).

Answer (score 1):

The type of the array in the structure is wrong; it should be `int arr[1000];`.

As written, you're using uninitialized variables all over the place; neither the `length` nor any of the pointers in your `arr` are set to anything reliable (though the pointers should be plain `int` anyway).  Because you have pointers instead of `int` in your stack, you have a very complex expression to access the stack (the `(*stack->arr)[stack->length++]`, etc), which should be much simpler, as in this rewritten code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int length;
    int arr[1000];
} Stack;

void push(Stack *stack, int el)
{
    stack->arr[stack->length++] = el;
}

int pop(Stack *stack)
{
    return stack->arr[--stack->length];
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack stack = { 0, { 0 } };
    push(&stack, 5);
    printf("%d\n", pop(&stack));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int length;
    int arr[1000];
} Stack;

void push(Stack *stack, int el) {
    (stack->arr)[stack->length++] = el;
}

int pop(Stack *stack) {
    return (stack->arr)[--stack->length];
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Stack stack;
    memset(&stack,0,sizeof(Stack));
    push(&stack, 5);
    printf("%d\n", pop(&stack));
    return 0;
}
```

The thumb rule is allocate memory before accessing it.

Comment: The parentheses in `(stack->arr)[stack->length++]` aren't really necessary, though they're not actually wrong.  Using `memset()` instead of an initializer works, but the compiler can do the job better.